# Swift - How do I store objects in cache as long as the app is running? - NSCache() gets cleared as soon as other vc gets displayed

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, swift4, nscache

I am trying to save a custom class to cache, so that it doesn't have to be downloaded every time the vc is getting called. 
My problem is though that the cache gets cleared when I open a different vc, so that when going back to the "old" vc no objects are stored in the cache anymore :(

I even tried: cache.evictsObjectsWithDiscardedContent = false

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use a singleton class to store your data temporarily.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @vivekDas how do I store instances of a singleton class in the cache?

Comment: You no need to store singleton class in cache, rather you can create singleton instance, and in the singleton class you can have all the data you want to save as long as your app is running.